# how to proxy crates.io in China

Tags: rust-cargo, great-firewall-of-china

The network in China is not well connected to the rest of the world. We have repository proxy for maven, for pypi, for yarn and so on. Do we have a repository proxy for `crates.io`?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two mirrors that I know of:

[USTC](https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/help/crates.io-index.html)

```
registry = "sparse+https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/crates.io-index/"
```

[Tsinghua University](https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/help/crates.io-index.git/)

```
registry = "sparse+https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/crates.io-index/"
```

To use the mirror, edit or create `$CARGO_HOME/config` file like the following:

```
[source.crates-io]
replace-with = 'ustc'

[source.ustc]
registry = "sparse+https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/crates.io-index/"
```

In Linux, you can try the following command to change the configuration:

```
mkdir -vp ${CARGO_HOME:-$HOME/.cargo}

cat << EOF | tee -a ${CARGO_HOME:-$HOME/.cargo}/config
[source.crates-io]
replace-with = 'ustc'

[source.ustc]
registry = "sparse+https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/crates.io-index"
EOF
```

In Windows, the default path to $CARGO_HOME is `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.cargo`.

---

Note that sparse registries are supported from Rust 1.68+. It is recommended to use them if you can, since they are much faster. If it is not supported for your environment, try the git registry:

```
registry = "git://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/crates.io-index"
```

Or, if git cannot be used, try the following:

```
registry = "https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/crates.io-index"
```